# Unable to test MatTable filling rows with Karma test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I would like to be helped in **understanding what's wrong** with my code approach. I tried to mimic the dynamics of [this tutorial about Harnesses](https://kevinkreuzer.medium.com/test-your-components-using-angular-materials-component-harnesses-f9c1deebdf5d)

I have the following Angular component, which is a straightfoward data table (`MatTable`) bound to a remote service. Instead of GoT characters, it works with system roles as part of an admin screen

roles.component.html

```
<div class="pb-3">
  <button class="btn btn-success" (click)=add()>Add</button>
</div>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceRole" matSort class="mat-table w-100">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dto">{{dto.roleId}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dto">{{dto.description}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="created">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Created<th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dto">{{dto.created | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="modified">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Modified</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dto">{{dto.modified | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="bottoni">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let dto">
      <button mat-button (click)=edit(dto.roleId)>
        <fa-icon icon="pencil-alt"></fa-icon>
      </button>
      <button mat-button (click)=delete(dto.roleId)>
        <fa-icon icon="recycle"></fa-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay" style="width: available;"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let myRowData; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
</table>
```

roles.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {RoleDto} from 'src/app/services/model/role-dto';
import {RoleService} from 'src/app/services/role.service';
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-roles',
  templateUrl: './roles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./roles.component.scss']
})
export class RolesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  columnsToDisplay: string[] = ['id', 'description', 'created', 'modified', 'bottoni'];
  dataSourceRole: MatTableDataSource<RoleDto> = new MatTableDataSource<RoleDto>([]);
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  private roles$?: Subscription;

  constructor(private roleService: RoleService,
              private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.dataSourceRole.sort = this.sort;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRoles();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.roles$?.unsubscribe();
  }

  getRoles(): void { //TODO: unsubscribe if needed. I found this issue while writing this post
    this.roles$ = this.roleService.getRoles()
      .subscribe({
        next: rolesData => this.dataSourceRole.data = rolesData,
        error: error => console.error(error),
      });
  }

  edit(roleID: string): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/roles', 'details', roleID]);
  }

  add(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/roles', 'new']);
  }

  delete(roleID: any): void {
    this.roleService.deleteRole(roleID)
      .subscribe({
        next: _ => this.getRoles(),
        error: error => console.error(error),
      });

  }

}
```

roles.component.spec.ts

```
import {ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, flush, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {RolesComponent} from './roles.component';
import {RoleService} from "../../services/role.service";
import {BehaviorSubject, Subject} from "rxjs";
import {RoleDto} from "../../services/model/role-dto";
import {HarnessLoader} from "@angular/cdk/testing";
import {TestbedHarnessEnvironment} from "@angular/cdk/testing/testbed";
import {MatTableHarness} from "@angular/material/table/testing";
import {RouterTestingModule} from "@angular/router/testing";
import {FormRoleComponent} from "./form-role/form-role.component";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import SpyObj = jasmine.SpyObj;

describe('RolesComponent', () => {
  let component: RolesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RolesComponent>;
  let roleService: RoleService;
  let roleServiceSpy: SpyObj<RoleService>;
  let loader: HarnessLoader;
  let router: Router;
  let returnedRoles = new Subject<RoleDto[]>(); //Explanation 1

  beforeEach(() => {
    roleServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(RoleService, ['getRoles', 'getRole', 'createRole', 'deleteRole', 'updateRole']);
    roleService = roleServiceSpy as RoleService;
    roleServiceSpy.getRoles.and.returnValue(returnedRoles);
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [RolesComponent],
      providers: [
        {provide: RoleService, useValue: roleService},
      ],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
        {
          path: 'roles/new',
          component: FormRoleComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'roles/:id',
          component: FormRoleComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'roles',
          component: RolesComponent,
        },])]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RolesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
  });

  afterEach(() => fixture.destroy());

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  /**
   * GIVEN
   * RoleService.getRoles returns 3 roles
   *
   * WHEN
   * Component is loaded
   *
   * THEN
   * Component displays 3 data rows
   * Rows contain text matching the role ID in its returned order
   */
  it('should display the rows when data is present', async () => {
    let roles: RoleDto[] = [
      {roleId: 'ADMIN', description: 'Admin role', created: new Date(), creator: 0, modified: new Date(), modifier: 0},
      {roleId: 'USER', description: 'User role', created: new Date(), creator: 0, modified: new Date(), modifier: 0},
      {roleId: 'READER', description: 'Reader role', created: new Date(), creator: 0, modified: new Date(), modifier: 0},
    ];
    returnedRoles.next(roles); //Explanation 1

    fixture.detectChanges();

    let tableHarness = await loader.getHarness(MatTableHarness);
    let rows = await tableHarness.getRows();
    expect(rows.length).toBe(roles.length); //Question
    for (const row of rows) { //This is untested and may be totally wrong
      const index = rows.indexOf(row);
      let text = (await row.getCellTextByIndex({columnName: 'ID'})).join(' ');
      let expected: string = roles[index].roleId!;
      expect(text).toContain(expected);
    }

  });
});
```

## Explanation 1

I struggled into making the data source work for hours. In my first release of the test, I had simply mocked the `getRoles()` method to return `Observable.of(thatArray)` but in the end I found during debugging that ngOnInit is called veeeeeeery early. So early that I didn't have time to mock the method that the `ngOnInit` completed along with its callbacks.

So I decided to return an Observable that I could control from my tests, one that will trigger the callback after I invoke `next`.

## Question

My test code is not working. The component works when invoked in a live application with a live remote server.

In the component tests, `rows` is an empty array.

### What I also tried

Changing the `Subject` to a `BehaviourSubject` initially returning an array of one role didn't change anything (test resulted in 0 rows).

Using fakeAsync didn't change. It looks like it's not required by harness tests because they are all asynchronous.

### Comment

I am struggling to provide working examples to my coders about using automated tests the proper way and I already spent enough hours in <strike>making tests work</strike> *learning how to teach how to write testing code* that I could be summoned anytime by my PM

> We'll do the tests manually the old school way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem was not importing `MatTableModule`, and perhaps `MaterialModule` as well. When I edited the question I had some compilation problems that failed to run the correct test code.

Once fixed, eveyrthing worked. Fix was to add the `MatTableModule` and `MaterialModule` to the `TestBed`

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [RolesComponent],
      providers: [
        {provide: RoleService, useValue: roleService},
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AmlcFontAwesomeModule,
        MaterialModule,
        MatTableModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          {
            path: 'roles/new',
            component: FormRoleComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'roles/:id',
            component: FormRoleComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'roles',
            component: RolesComponent,
          },])]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });
```

Comment: Exactly! I had the similar issue I couldn't query by selector from `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement`. But finally it worked after importing 'MatTableModule'.